# Angular redirecting to homepage when calling splice() with ng-repeat and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is a very odd problem which I don't quite know how to describe or troubleshoot. I have a function `addattack` inside a directive:

```
scope.addattack = function () {
    var attack = {
    }
    scope.attacks.push(attack) 
}
```

`attacks` is an array inside the scope of my main controller. I also have a function `deleteattack`:

```
scope.deleteattack = function (i) {
    console.log(scope.attacks)
    scope.attacks.splice(scope.attacks.indexOf(i), 1)
    console.log(scope.attacks)
}
```

Which I am calling from my directive html:

```
<div class="character-input input-group input-group-sm col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10" ng-repeat="attack in attacks">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="attack-{{attack.name}}">Attack</span>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteattack(attack)">Delete Attack</button>

</div>
```

I know that the `indexOf` and the `splice` are working correctly because of the console logs. However, a second after I call `deleteattack` I get kicked out of my current page and am redirected back to the home page. Almost as if my entire session is destroyed. I know it has something to do with the `splice()`. I just don't know what else is happening. I feel like it has something to do with the fact that I have an ng-repeat here and other ng-model's attached to this object elsewhere in my page, and that when I remove this object I am "destroying" the connection between the two so angular freaks out and redirects me. Is this the problem? Is there a way of solving this?

Comment: What are you using for routing? Angular doesn't "freak out and redirect" out of the box, so I suspect that's a feature you somehow added. ;-)

Comment: Added in answer below - was to long for a comment.

Comment: This piece of code seems to be fine. What do you mean by other ng-model is attached? can you show us more code? I don't think your problem is in this piece of code.

Comment: when you say that you are "redirected to the home page", are you sure that it's a redirect, and not just the same page with an empty list?

Comment: Ziv: I have several inputs with ng-models that reference some properties on my attack object (I removed them from the original post to conserve space). Here is what one looks like: 
<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="character-{{attack.name}}" ng-model="attack.name" ng-change="recalculate()">

Claies: When I execute the function deleteattack I am redirected from the page: http://localhost:1337/characters/character-sheet/Iph/5681a8c27773fdbe742406fa
to http://localhost:1337/# 
I'm pretty sure it's not the same page just empty, though I may be wrong.

Comment: please take a look in this jsbin code: http://jsbin.com/fuyisa/edit?html,js,output this codes does the same thing, but without any redirect...

Comment: Joaozito: I wish it were that simple. Your code just pops off the 0 index of the array. I'm trying to remove a specific object from the array. I know I can use indexOf and pass in the result, but that's exactly what I'm doing in my original code. Plus I know the array splicing works, it's just the unintended redirect that's holding me up.

Comment: I've updated his fiddle with one that sounds like your problem, still maintain theres something else doing the redirect, as it doesn't redirect on splice. http://jsbin.com/lurubozaha/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have encountered this issue before - not exactly sure why it happens, managed to resolved it like this:

```
scope.deleteattack = function (i) {
           var attacks = angular.copy(scope.attacks);
           var indexToRemove = scope.attacks.indexOf(i);
           attacks.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
           scope.attacks = attacks;
        }
```

Comment: And then, is the problem the use of splice directly over a scoped variable? I will try with angular 1.5 for some light on this problem.

Comment: It's still bringing me back to the home page. The line scope.attacks = attacks is what's causing it.

Comment: Wow, even by simply having the function change scope.attacks to an array or a string, it causes a redirect.

Comment: @JN18 It's a strange issue.. have you tried removing other references to `scope.attacks` to see if the problem could be related to those. Also, try putting you're call to `array.splice()` in a `$timeout`.

Comment: I got it!
`code`
scope.deleteattack = function (i) {
               var attacks = angular.copy(scope.attacks);
               var indexToRemove = scope.attacks.indexOf(i);
               attacks.splice(indexToRemove, 1)

                setTimeout(function(){
                    scope.attacks = attacks; 
                    scope.$digest();
                }, 0);
            }   `code`

To be honest I'm still not 100% sure what is happening but here's my theory: When I hit the delete button, the object was getting deleted but the DOM was not updating, so the delete button was still there...

Comment: When I hit the button a second time, something happened and angular totally reset, sending me back to the home page. However, when I manually forced a digest along with a settimeout (both steps are necessary) the DOM was able to update properly. It must have something to do with the order angular is sending things to the call stack, although what specifically is happening I don't know. But thank you Foreign Object!

Comment: @JN18 I'm glad I could help! I had a similar issue - I was just hoping I could prevent a bit of pain.

Comment: Last addition: this code works better `scope.deleteattack = function (i) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    scope.attacks.splice(scope.attacks.indexOf(i), 1)
                    scope.$digest();
                }, 0);
            }   `

Since the other one was leaving the old object still in the array on the controller scope.

Comment: I think you don't have to use time out.